# Concatenate three javascript arrays in one array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have three arrays :

```
a = [1,2,3];
b = [a,b,c];
c = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
```

I need to generate this array: `test = [[1,2,3], [a,b,c], ['red', 'blue', 'green']]`.

I have tried: `[].implode(a,b,c)`,
but it does not give me the array i need.

Comment: Are you sure, you’re asking about JavaScript?

Comment: What does `{}` mean in the context of arrays? and what's wrong with `test = [a, b, c]`

Comment: `var a,b,c;` `var d = a.concat(b,c);`

Comment: are `a`, `b`, and `c` defined elsewhere? I'd normally link to mcve or how to ask, but OP, I truly think you need to spend more time researching fundamentals before asking questions. At least to get the vocabulary and syntax in line.

Comment: @Xufox yes i am sure

Comment: `.implode()` doesn't exist in javascript. Why don't you just use: `var test = [a,b,c]` ?

Comment: @Nisarg it doesn't give me the result i need. If I do this: var d = a.concat(b,c); the result is [1,2,3,a,b,c,'red', 'blue', 'green']. I need a different result

Comment: @CalvinNunes Thank you Calvin. That gave me the right result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `[a,b,c]` is `['a','b','c]`, simply put them in a new array:

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = ['a','b','c'];
var c = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

var test = [a, b, c];

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstood your requirements then this is what you need,

**Object of Array's:**

```js
a = [1, 2, 3];
b = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
c = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

result = [a,b,c];
required = {};
result.forEach(function(element, index) {
  required[index] = element;
  return required;
})

console.log(required);
```

**Array of Array's**

```js
a = [1, 2, 3];
b = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
c = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

result = [a, b, c];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of writing `[...a]` when it is equal to a?

Comment: I wast just thinking many things at one time :) :( :P. That was my bad. Edited. Thanks for pointing me out